# Adding custom elements on react native swiper tiles

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the react-native-deck-swiper for a project, my question is how do I add custom parameters like images, custom html elements to the tiles. Is there a way to add these to the cards array?

Currently the cards array is structured like:

```
cards: ["1","2","3"]
```

Is there a way to structure it so that I can pull in custom parameters like so:

```
cards: [{name:"1", image:"imageurl", age:"43"},{name:"2", image:"imageurl", age:"22"}]
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `Card` component, and pass the data as props:

```js
const Cards = [
  { name: "1", image: "imageurl", age: "43" },
  { name: "2", image: "imageurl", age: "22" },
];

const Card = props =>
  <View>
    <Image source={props.image} />
    <Text>
      {props.name}, {props.age}
    </Text>
  </View>;

<DeckSwiper cards={Cards} renderCard={props => <Card {...props} />} />;
```

Comment: i'm getting an "undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.props.image')" error